# Expressing "super" generics in Kotlin functional types?

Tags: java, generics, rx-java, kotlin, rx-kotlin

I'm trying to port an RxJava library and leverage extension functions in Kotlin.

```
fun <T,R: MutableCollection<T>> Observable<T>.collectWhile(factory: (() -> R), condition: (R,T) -> Boolean) =
        compose(Transformers.collectWhile(factory,condition))
```

The `Transformers.collectWhile()` is written in Java and has this signature:

```
public static <T, R extends Collection<T>> Transformer<T, R> collectWhile(final Func0<R> factory,
            final Action2<? super R, ? super T> collect)
```

However, I am getting an issue with mapping the `collect` argument and I'm not good at generics. How do I express `super` with a functional type?

**UPDATE**

Stupid mistake on my part. I should not have been posting on SO late at night.

I was actually targeting this

```
public static <T, R extends Iterable<?>> Transformer<T, R> collectWhile(final Func0<R> factory,
        final Action2<? super R, ? super T> collect, final Func2<? super R, ? super T, Boolean> condition)
```

And this is what I should have done.

```
fun <T,R: MutableCollection<T>> Observable<T>.collectWhile(factory: (() -> R), action: (R,T) -> Unit, condition: (R,T) -> Boolean) =
    compose(Transformers.collectWhile(factory,action,condition))
```

Comment: please add the error message you are getting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java wildcard type `? super T` corresponds to `in T` [use-site type projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) in Kotlin, so the corresponding type of `collect` parameter would be `Action2<in R, in T>`.

That type is roughly equivalent (or more specifically is eligible for [SAM-conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)) to `(R, T) -> Unit` functional type in Kotlin, because `(R, T) -> Unit` is a synonym for type `Function2<R, T, Unit>` and the latter is equivalent to `Function2<in R, in T, out Unit>` due to the [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) of the Function2 type parameters.

You cannot pass a function of type `(R, T) -> Boolean` as an argument to `collect`, where `(R, T) -> Unit` is expected.

Either change the type of `collect` parameter, or the type of `condition` parameter`.

Comment: Oh man now I feel stupid. It was late at night when I did this. I'll update my answer.